# Разработка класса

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

После изучения языка С начала изучать язык С++. Пытаюсь создать экземпляр класса с помощью конструктора и не понимаю, почему появляются ошибки, потому что делаю в точности как в учебнике. Работаю в Visual Studio 2019, также пыталась работать в Visual Studio 2015. Прикрепляю код и несколько ошибок, которые выдает компилятор. Всего их 22 и они однотипные. Подозреваю, что проблема в настройках IDE.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;


class ThinkingPlayer {
    string player;
    char sign;
public:
    ThinkingPlayer(string, char);
    string getName();
    char getSign();
};

ThinkingPlayer::ThinkingPlayer(string name, char symbol) {
    ThinkingPlayer::player = name;
    ThinkingPlayer::sign = symbol;
    cout << 'Good';
}
string ThinkingPlayer::getName() {
    return ThinkingPlayer::player;
}
char ThinkingPlayer::getSign() {
    return ThinkingPlayer::sign;
}
int main()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter your name: \n";
    getline(cin, name);
    ThinkingPlayer* player1 = new ThinkingPlayer(name, '%');
}
```

[image: Ошибки компилятора]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема на в IDE, а в настройках проекта, вы используете предварительно скомпилированные заголовки `"stdafx.h"`. Это такой механизм в VisualStudio для увеличения скорости компиляции.

Для рашения пробелмы поместите `"stdafx.h"` на первое место, и заработает, либо отключите этот механизм в настройках: `Свойства Проекта->Свойства конфигурации->C\C++->Предварительно откомпилированный заголовок`